# How to get two likert variables properly into one (ggplot2) sj.likert plot of the sjPlot package?

Tags: r, sjplot

I have a dataframe with two likert variables. I want to plot these two variables by using the `sjp.likert` function of the `sjPlot` package. The plot doesn't make sense.

My data (`mydf`) looks like this:

```
structure(list(var1 = c(1, 1, 5, NA, 3, NA, 1, NA, 4, 3, 5, 5, 
4, 2, 2, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA), var2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 3, NA, 
5, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, 1, 1)), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

   var1 var2
1     1   NA
2     1   NA
3     5   NA
4    NA    3
5     3   NA
6    NA    3
7     1   NA
8    NA    5
9     4   NA
10    3   NA
11    5   NA
12    5    2
13    4   NA
14    2   NA
15    2   NA
16   NA    4
17   NA    4
18    5   NA
19   NA    1
20   NA    1
```

This is the code I use:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(RColorBrewer)

likert_5 <- mydf
levels_5 <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5))
varnames <- names(likert_5
sjp.likert(likert_5, legendLabels=levels_5, barColor="brewer",legendSize=0.5,axisLabelSize=0.5,valueLabelSize=2,colorPalette="BrBG", orderBy="pos",legendPos="bottom",axisLabels.y=varnames)
```

This is the result:

[image]

I think you agree that this doesn't make sense at all. The two variable names are the same and there are four levels instead of five. Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can make it a bit simpler for us to answer your question: Using `dput(yourDF)` in R gives you code you can dump here that allows us to reconstruct your data within seconds.

Comment: Hi Jaap, thanks for the suggestion. I added the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the `sjp.likert` function. Adding arguments one by one, I found that the plot works fine until the argument `orderBy = "pos"`is included. Examining the source code of the function shows:

```
sjp.likert
# ...
# questionCount <- nrow(pos)/(length(legendLabels)/2)
# if (!is.null(orderBy)) {
#   ...
#   orderUniqueItems <- rev(1 + questionCount - orderUniqueItems)
#   axisLabels.y <- axisLabels.y[orderUniqueItems]
# }
# ...
```

Using your data, I end up with the following:

```
questionCount
# [1] 1.6
orderUniqueItems
# [1] 1.6 0.6
varnames[c(1.6, 0.6)]
# [1] "var1"
```

I think the author actually wanted `questionCount <-`**ceiling**(`orderUniqueItems <- c(unique(orderRelatedItems)))`, which with your data would produce:

```
questionCount
# [1] 2
orderUniqueItems
# [1] 2 1
varnames[c(1.6, 0.6)]
# [1] "var2" "var1"
```

A quick fix would be to save the returned plot and modify the labels manually (using the author's code to create the labels with 'n=' pasted on).

```
for (i in 1:length(varnames)) {
  varnames[i] <- paste(varnames[i], sprintf(" (n=%i)", length(na.omit(likert_5[,i]))), sep = "")
}
myplot <- sjp.likert(likert_5, legendLabels=levels_5, barColor="brewer", legendSize=0.5, axisLabelSize=0.5, valueLabelSize=2, colorPalette="BrBG", orderBy="pos", legendPos="bottom")
myplot$plot + scale_x_discrete(labels=varnames[c(2,1)])
```

---

Edit:

Regarding the missing middle level, I also found this in the code:

```
if (!is.null(neutral)) {
  out <- out[out$Response != neutral, ]
}
```

Which deletes the middle 'neutral' category from the output. There doesn't seem to be an option to change this, and none of [the author's examples](http://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/plotting-likert-scales-net-stacked-distributions-with-ggplot-rstats/) use an odd number of categories. So it seems to be a feature, rather than a bug.

You might consider the `likert` package, specifically the function `likert.bar.plot` with the argument `include.center = TRUE`.

Comment: JVL thanks for the research! I set the "orderBy" to NULL and a part of my problem was solved (so I didn't use your quick fix), but the other part still remains: there are four likert values in the plot whilst there are five in my data. Any ideas about how to tackle that problem?

Comment: I edited my answer to address that issue, but it doesn't look like there's an easy way around it.

Comment: thanks! I used the likert package before, but I ran into too many issues regarding missing levels. But I can give a try again.

Comment: I'm not happy with the current implementation of the sjp.likert function in my package. However, I completely rewrote the function and am now trying to include it. As the new likert-functions used R base graphics, I'm probably add the new likert-function as alternative, not replacing the old function that uses ggplot. @JVL: Thanks for your hint, I'll look at the code for possible bugs.